# Difference "exam class" and "eqexam package"?

Tags: packages, document-classes, exam

- What's the difference? It looks like "eqexam package" is more advanced. The "exam class" just uses the identical commands from "eqexam package".
- Is one of the two outdated? Recent posts talk only about the "exam class".

Comment: they are just different classes by different people. Both related to exams. exam is in texlive so most people will have it, eqexam is not, probably because of the reliance on acrotex.

Comment: You mean one is a class and the other one a package. But they use both identical the same commands like "\fillin[]" or "\solutions". Its like one just copied from the other... If you are in texlive, just load the (more advanced) package and you are done.

Comment: I had a quick look at the doc and I see no evidence of any shared code or development any similarity in command names is just coincidence I think. But I don't have eqexam so leave for someone else to answer.

Comment: Why than go through the trouble, he could just used "eqexam package". Most seem to prefer "exam class". Why? A package instead of a class seems more flexible.

Comment: a class seems more suited than a package really but exam.cls seems to have started around 1994 was eqexam available? But that's how software development works, why have amsart if there is article, or memoir if there is koma or tikz if there is pstricks. There is always room for alternative parallel development.